# AngularJS: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] from angular include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] from just the angular include, I'm guessing since there's not a whole lot more.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=demo&p1=Error%3A%20…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4920
    at p (angular.js:402)
    at g (angular.js:4880)
    at eb (angular.js:4802)
    at c (angular.js:1909)
    at Pc (angular.js:1930)
    at ue (angular.js:1815)
    at angular.js:33340
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3435)
```

Comment: That's it ? Any extra code ? Are you just referencing angular from this CDN and it is throwing error ?

Comment: That is all I have after I stripped out a lot to narrow down the source of the problem. I should have continued just a bit longer before posting... I can get rid of the error now when I also remove the ng-app="demo" part.

Comment: you are getting this error because `demo` app is not yet defined. Put this code and test <script type="text/javascript">var demoApp= angular.module('demoApp', []);</script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write `ng-app="demo"` but dont have script file js . Pls add it

```
(function(){
 angular.module('demo',[]);
})()
```

and add in html

```
<script src="script.js></script>
```